# Loop through array, convert strings to array, push to new array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration, each

I'm currently working on a project where I need to loop through an array of strings, convert those strings into arrays, and push those arrays into a larger array. Some of the strings have word duplication, so I need to remove that as well. I want to avoid hard-coding everything, so I'm trying to write as many functions as I can.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
old_array = ['Lilies are lovely lovely', 'Roses are romantic romantic', 'Daisies are bright bright']

new_array = []
```

Here's what the new array should look like:

```
new_array = [['Lilies', 'are', 'lovely'], ['Roses', 'are', 'romantic'], ['Daisies', 'are', 'bright']]
```

So the strings from old_array must be transformed into sub-arrays, with duplicate words removed.

I've been trying this and variations for a while, and it's not working very well.

```
def s_to_a(array)
  array.each do |string|
    string.split(" ").uniq
    new_array.push(string) #pretty sure this is incorrect
  end
end

s_to_a(old_array)
```

The error I keep getting is that new_array is an undefined local variable because I initialized it outside the function. Am I going about this the wrong way? Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: What is the desired result if `old_array = ['a b b', 'b a b']`? If `old_array = ['pound a pound of nails]`?

Comment: Put `new_array = []` as the first line inside your method, then your code works. But as @Cam says you should use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

This sort of thing is easiest done with `map`, like so:

```
new_array = old_array.map{|s| s.split.uniq }
```

---

#### Details

`map` is an `Enumerable` method that converts or "maps" the enumerable object it is called on (often an `array`) into a new `array`.  This is more convenient than manually pushing into sub-arrays with nil-checking.

The `String` method `split` by default splits on whitespace characters, so we can just call it without an argument and it will return an array of words.  *For a bit more detail... `split` uses `$;` as its default parameter, which is Ruby's global **field separator** variable...  if the field separator is nil, which it is by default, `split` defaults to whitespace separation*.

Comment: Everyone learning Ruby should spend some time looking through the multitude of methods available in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) library as many of these are extremely handy. `map` is one such method, but there are dozens of others.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip about map!